# How to move cursor one step backward in QLineEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt

How to move cursor one step backward in QLineEdit in Qt?

Any help is appreciated.

I tried

```
pLineEdit->cursorBackward(true,1);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: if `cursorBackward()` does not work, then what does `cursorPosition()` return?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to undo you just call undo function.
If you want to go one character back you can use cursorBackward.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#cursorPosition-prop

Use `cursorPosition()` to get the current position and then use `setCursorPosition()` to set it one step backward.

Comment: I tried this also  int pos = pLineEdit->cursorPosition();           
             
              pLineEdit->setCursorPosition(pos -1); but it does not set the text one step backward, but when i debug it shows me correct cursor position.

Comment: "set the text one step backward"... Did you mean "cursor" or do you really mean "text"?

Comment: are you trying to implement backspace? or undo function?

Answer (score 0):

`void   QLineEdit::cursorBackward ( bool mark, int steps = 1 );` is exactly what you want, see [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#cursorBackward)